# Backbone Router not triggering route

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following router:

```
appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'inbox',
    'inbox': 'inbox',
    'discussions_engagement': 'contacts',
  },

  inbox: function(page) {
    console.log('inbox');
    var page = page || 1;
    engage.app.hydrateInbox(page, engage.app.showInbox);
  },
  ....
};
```

When I am on http://[...]/#inbox and I call

```
appRouter.navigate('inbox', {trigger: true});
```

the inbox action doesn't fire which is what I want to achieve.  Now I have looked at the source of Backbone (https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1027) and I see that it doesn't support what I'm trying to do but is there some way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but maybe a solution (if I get you correctly): (Re-)Render your page / your most parent view, e.g. `appView.render()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create an event manager in your engage.app object, like this:

```
var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

Then in your router do this for the inbox route:

```
vent.trigger('inbox:show', page);
```

And handle that event in the engage.app object, doing the code there that used to be in the route handler.

Now, instead of calling `appRouter.navigate` you can trigger that same event.

Also, from that handler, you can call `appRouter.navigate('inbox');` without passing true. Now you can get your app to the state you want without trying to force the route.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing; seems like a half-decent solution although it does create some extra code.

Comment: @JasonStonebraker [This link](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/28/dont-execute-a-backbone-js-route-handler-from-your-code/) explains the idea. This pattern has worked well for me.  It leaves the router with a single job, which is routing based on browser URL changes.  This question was about trying to trigger a route when you are already on that route.  This solution is not a workaround (IMO) but a better design.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell... As of Backbone 0.9.10 using `appRouter.navigate('inbox', {trigger: true});` works as expected.

Comment: The Backbone source still has this: `if (this.fragment === fragment) return;`, so I think Gavin's problem still exists.  Also, source has a comment: 'The options object can contain `trigger: true` if you wish to have the route callback be fired (not usually desirable)'.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is just to call the method

```
appRouter.inbox();
```